# How to add custom language to wpml_browser_redirect_params

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I do not want the /zh-hans as a suffix of the translated Chinese pages of my website which is English by default.

So I added a custom language via WPML ->Languages->Edit languages and add a new custom language for Chinese. Added the desired language code of "cn" and made sure to use a different default locale from the original language.

The problem is that when I enable the "Browser language redirect" option, the Chinese browser does not recognize and redirect to the /cn directory because this output is generated:

```
    var wpml_browser_redirect_params = {
    "pageLanguage":"en",
    "languageUrls":{
        "en_US":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest",
        "en":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest",
        "US":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest",
        "de_DE":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/de\/",
        "de":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/de\/",
        "DE":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/de\/",
        "ja":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/ja\/",
        "pl_PL":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/pl\/",
        "pl":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/pl\/",
        "PL":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/pl\/",
        "cn_CN":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
        "cn":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
        "CN":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
        "nl_NL":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/nl\/",
        "nl":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/nl\/",
        "NL":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/nl\/",
    },
    "cookie":{
        "name":"_icl_visitor_lang_js",
        "domain":"dev.webber.nl",
        "path":"\/innovatest\/",
        "expiration":24
    }
};
```

I would like to add the following to this "languageUrls" list:

```
"zh_CN":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"zh":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"ZH":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"zh_SG":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"sg":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"SG":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"zh_TW":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"tw":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"TW":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"zh_HK":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"hk":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
"HK":"https:\/\/dev.webber.nl\/innovatest\/cn\/",
```

Is this possible? Please help!